# efficiently rotate bitmap android canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am working on a live wallpaper with several bitmaps. The bitmaps are to rotate continuously. This is how I am rotating one bitmap:

```
public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);          
            planet_1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.planet_1);
}

void draw(){
                         Matrix m_planet1 = new Matrix();

                     m_planet1.setRotate(r_planet1++,
                                planet_1.getWidth() / 2,
                                planet_1.getHeight() / 2);
                        m_planet1.postTranslate(
                                c.getWidth() / 2 - planet_1.getWidth() / 2,
                                c.getHeight() - planet_1.getHeight());

                        c.drawBitmap(planet_1, m_planet1, p1);
                        r_planet1 = r_planet1++;}
```

This works fine for one bitmap but I want to have more than 10 bitmaps rotating at different speeds. When I do this for the 10 bitmaps, it starts to lag. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hardware accelerated SurfaceView like this:

In the manifest, add this to your application section:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

In onCreate, do this:

```
setWillNotDraw(false); // Turns on drawing for SurfaceView, disabled by default
```

Then, in onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        ...do you drawing...

        invalidate(); // Triggers redraw
}
```

Also, instead of rotating each planet, try moving the canvas around instead, that is usually simpler and probably quicker as well.

```
c.save();
c.translate(centerOfPlanetX, centerOfPlanetY);
c.rotate(numDegrees);
c.drawBitmap(.....);
c.restore();
```